# Problems with associations in Rails, adding many events to one group

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two migrations as below:

```
CreateGroups
  t.string :name
  t.string :groupkey

CreateEvents
  t.string :name
  t.string :groupkeyname
  t.integer :group_id
```

and their corresponding models:

```
group
  has_many :events

event
  belongs_to :group
```

from what I understand is that the t.integer :group_id column in the CreateEvents migration references the default id column in the CreateGroups migration. Now I create a group:

```
g = Group.create(:name => "skydive", :groupkey => "withwingsuit")
```

However, when I create an event like this:

```
Event.create(:name => "whatever", :group_id => 1)
```

and try to print g.events there is nothing it gives me: []

Why doesn't it give the event i just created ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may need to refresh the association because it may be cached locally. After adding the new event try this.

```
g.events(true)
```

that will force Rails to retrieve items again from the DB.

Comment: do you know how to make the groupkeyname in CreateEvents reference the groupkey in CreateGroups... just like group_id references the default id !!